# IE 11 Long running script. How to debug which script is produce this?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm getting a popup in IE 11 browser 'long running script' and page stocks. How can I find what script is producing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I used to find the problem script.

1) View page source on the browser without issue.

2) Save source to HTML file.

3) Place file to the same domain so it can load domain related files.

4) One by one remove javascript from HTML code and checking if an issue has gone on IE browser.

Comment: This required a huge patient.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar actually it is simple and 100% working steps. It will not required huge patient unless you have thousands of scripts on your page.

Comment: but yes, it is not super fun at all

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 to open the "Developer Tools Interface". Change to the Network-Tab and refresh your page. It should show you what is using how much time to load.

Comment: in my case browser stucks, and I can't really use its tools.

Comment: Open a new empty browser window. Open the tools first and then browse to the page with the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use dev tools, but in my case information how much time script loading useless. I need information about script execution time.